# RFCs for implementing HTTP server

Tags: http, server, project, rfc, rfc2616

I'm thinking to start a side project to learn how HTTP servers are built.

I started searching for it and came to know that the specifications are mentioned in RFC documents.

But there are [over 8200 RFCs as of August 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RFCs).

Further searching about it got me specific RFC to use for HTTP i.e., [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) on software engineering stackexchange [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/200827/295520). There is a comment that says "[In 2014, RFC2616 was replaced by multiple RFCs (7230-7237).](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200821/how-to-write-a-http-server/200829#comment630840_200827)"

So, do we need to abandon RFC2616 completely and read RFCs(7230-7237)?

We can clearly see on [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/search/rfc_search_detail.php?rfc=2616&pubstatus%5B%5D=Any&pub_date_type=any) that `Obsoleted by RFC 7230, RFC 7231, RFC 7232, RFC 7233, RFC 7234, RFC 7235`.

So, what are the RFCs for building HTTP server? Should I only read the documents mentioned as **Obsoleted by**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need RFCs 7230..7236 (for HTTP/1.1) and RFC 7540+7541 (for HTTP/2).

Comment: And for HTTP/2?